# Script that handles opening a non-existing file, 'unknown_file.txt', and prints the message File not found. to the user

Tags: python

- I am trying to write a script in Python that handles opening a
  non-existing file, 'unknown_file.txt', and prints the message File
  not found. to the user.
- Use try ... except clauses. Print the user message inside except
  clause.

**The code which I tried was :**

```
try:
  f= open("unknown.txt")

except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

**Actual result basis above code:**

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unknown_file.txt'
```

Comment: just change the `print` statement to print what you want

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you:

```
import os

file_exists = os.path.isfile('FILEPATH')
if file_exists:
   print('File Exists')
else:
    print('File Does Not Exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is coming due to the description that written inside FileNotFoundError exception class. For your actual intended message to appear in screen, try the below code:

try:
    f = open("unknown_file.txt")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print("File not found")

Answer (score 0):

```py
try: 
    fname = "unknown.txt" 
    fopen = open(fname, "r") 
except FileNotFoundError: 
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To improve readability, you may try [formatting your code using code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).